# gdb not opening exe file

Tags: disassembly

I'm trying to open an exe with gdb but although it seems to run I'm unable to list or disas anything. The file is obfuscated, and I may be answering my own question here, with nine rays .net obfuscator.

Does this mean I'm unable to use a debugger or should I be able to open with a debugger such as idapro or gdb but have stuff missing?

When in gdb I run (gdb)file name.exe I get the message 'Reading symbols from name.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.'

The output from linux files command is 'PE32 excutable (console Intel 80386 Mono/.Net Assembly, for MS Windows'

Thanks

Comment: No binary format handler is defined in the Linux kernel for PE binary files. As a result the kernel will not compose a process image in virtual memory from a PE binary. No process image means no debugging since there is nothing for ptrace to attach to. https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a quick and dirty raw disassembly of a short snippet, you can load the relevant part of the exe using gdb's [restore](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html#Dump_002fRestore-Files) command.  It is easier to first, extract the snippet, for example:

```
tail -c +4096 the-program-with-the-snippet.exe | head -c 1024 > snippet
```

Then, you need to start debugging a dummy program and replace its main function with the snippet you want to disassemble.  For example::

```
~/tmp$ gdb -q dummy
Reading symbols from dummy...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x79f: file dummy.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ale/tmp/dummy 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8) at dummy.c:9
9       for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
(gdb) restore snippet binary main
Restoring binary file snippet into memory (0x555555554790 to 0x555555554b90)
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555554790 <+0>:     add    %bh,-0x35(%rdi)
   0x0000555555554793 <+3>:     movabs 0xa1cba872a376f272,%eax
   0x000055555555479c <+12>:    jb     0x555555554806 <main+118>
   0x000055555555479e <+14>:    cmp    0x72a270b7(%rdx,%rsi,2),%esp
   0x00005555555547a5 <+21>:    loopne 0x5555555547c2 <main+50>
   0x00005555555547a7 <+23>:    movabs 0xa1cd0572a12b0f72,%eax
   0x00005555555547b0 <+32>:    jb     0x5555555547c2 <main+50>
   0x00005555555547b2 <+34>:    pop    %rsi
   0x00005555555547b3 <+35>:    movabs %eax,0xa1d13272a1cd3a72
   0x00005555555547bc <+44>:    jb     0x5555555547b5 <main+37>
   0x00005555555547be <+46>:    loopne 0x555555554760 <frame_dummy>
   0x00005555555547c0 <+48>:    jb     0x5555555547a6 <main+22>
   0x00005555555547c2 <+50>:    iret   
...
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Of course, any format information (symbols and the like) is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to debug a Windows executable on a Linux machine with `gdb` without installing and configuring components that are required. @SYS_V explained it very well in his comment.

If you want to debug a Windows executable on Linux you have several ways to do so. I recommend you to check out a specific one - [Winedbg](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winedbg).

---

In addition, since you mentioned that you want to debug a `.net` application I'd suggest you check out [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) and [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), both are for Windows systems. de4dot can be used to deobfuscate `.net` obfuscated applications where dnSpy will allow you to decompile and debug `.net` applications.

Disassembling a `.net` applications is not a best practice since usually you'll only see the Intermediate Language ([CIL/MSIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)). `.net` decompilers are able to show you the original source code of the application.

If you want to decompile `.net` applications on Linux you can try with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) or [Mono decompiler](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-04.html).